# Connection on a vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, connections

I'm working through some lecture notes by Domingo Toledo, he says:

> Let $E \rightarrow M$ be a smooth bundle over a smooth manifold. We write $A^0(E)$ for the space of smooth sections of $E$ and $A^k(E)$ for the space of smooth sections of the vector bundle $\wedge^k(T^*M) \otimes E$. Alternatively, $A^k(E)= A^k(M) \otimes_{A^0(M)}A^0(E).$
> And then he gives the following definition:
> Definition: A connection on $E$ is an $\mathbb{R}-$ linear map $\nabla: A^0(E) \rightarrow  A^1(E)$ with the property that
> $$\nabla(fs) = df \otimes s + f\nabla s$$
> holds for all $f \in A^0(E)$ an all sections $s$.
> If $p \in M$ and $X \in T_pM$, and $i_X : T_p^*M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denotes evaluation at $X$, then we write
> $$ \nabla_X s = (i_X \otimes id)\nabla s.$$

My question is about $\nabla_Xs$, I understand it as follow, but I'm not sure if I am right:

If we fix a point $ m \in M$, then  ${(\nabla s)}_m$ is defined from $T^*_m M$ and takes values in the fiber $E_m$. If we fix $X \in T_pM$ and $T \in T^*_m M$, then $\nabla_Xs = T(X) {(\nabla s)}_m(T)$?

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is incorrect. In particular, I'm not sure why you introduced $T$ when there is no $T$ in the expression $\nabla_Xs$.

Here's a slightly different (but completely equivalent) way to think of $\nabla_Xs$. Note that $$\nabla s \in A^1(E) = \Gamma(M, T^*M\otimes E) \cong \Gamma(M, \operatorname{Hom}(TM, E)).$$ If $X \in \Gamma(M, TM)$, then $(\nabla s)(X) \in \Gamma(M, E)$ is denoted $\nabla_Xs$.

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael albanese for your answer! I actually introduce T because I was thinking in the following way : $\nabla_X$ is defined using $i_X$ and $i_X$ is a map from $T_m^*M$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which takes an element $T \in T_m^*M$ and to $T(X) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sure, but $i_X\otimes\operatorname{id}$ is a map $T^*M\otimes E \to E$. Given that $\nabla s \in \Gamma(M, T^*M\otimes E)$, we have $(i_X\otimes\operatorname{id})(\nabla s) = \nabla_Xs \in \Gamma(X, E)$. That is, $i_X$ acts on the $T^*M$ piece of $\nabla s$.